# Error import from .csv to table - Postgres - AWS-RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Error when importing csv file to postgres database in AWS RDS:

**Code:**

```
COPY public."tableTest" FROM 'C:\Temp\tableTest.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'LATIN1';
```

**Erro:**

[image]

*If I try to import it into my postgres on my desktop, it works. The error only happens in RDS and I am using the same database structure.*

Answer (score 1):

I managed to import the .csv through the Windows terminal with the following command:

> psql --host xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port 5432
>   --username postgres --dbname newDatabase -c "\copy public.tableTest FROM 'C:\Temp\tableTest.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING
>   'LATIN1';"